# What is the order of preference when we mix function and string type token definitions in ply.lex?

Tags: python, lex, lexer, ply

```
tokens = (
        NUMBER2,
        NUMBER1,
        )

def t_NUMBER1(t):
    r '[0-9]+'
    return t

t_NUMBER2 = r '[0-9][0-9]'
```

If I use the above token specifications in `ply.lex` then which token will get higher preference?
I know that in case of functions, the ones defined first have higher preference
and in case of strings, the bigger lengthed regular expressions have a higher preference.

What about when I have a mixture of `both string and function type` token specifications? And does the order in the `tokens = ()` tuple affect the preference order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the doc](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6):

> Internally, lex.py uses the re module to do its patten matching. When
>   building the master regular expression, rules are added in the
>   following order:
>
> 1. All tokens defined by functions are added in the same order as they appear in the lexer file.
> 2. Tokens defined by **strings are added next** by sorting them in order of decreasing regular expression length (longer expressions are added
>      first).

*If* this is correct, tokens defined by a function have higher "priority" than those defined by string.

Comment: I did see the docs and I have paraphrased a bit of it in my question but I missed the word `next` in the second rule. Thanks for pointing it out.